# GsonRequest has problems to parse a Map

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I use GsonRequest to serialize my data. However I have this situation:

This is the data in JSON:

```
[...] 
"u": {
      "53bde5b5e4fc4978c0000015": {
          "la": 40.772673,
          "lo": 9.6657388
     }, ...
```

And I serialize the data with:

```
public class ClusterResult extends SingleElement{
    public Integer count;
    public ClusterData[] c;
    public HashMap<String, ClusterUnit> u;
}
```

(with Map is just the same)

Any idea of how to change that? I use the GsonRequest class to serialize the data ( https://gist.github.com/ficusk/5474673 ).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to wrap your `ClusterUnit` in a class and use a custom deserializer?. Maybe I don't get what your problem is, if is like that, let me know. This is how I did it:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author astinx
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().run();
    }

    public class ClusterUnitWrapped {
        String id; //53bde5b5e4fc4978c0000015
        Double la;
        Double lo;

        private ClusterUnitWrapped(String id, Double la, Double lo) {
            this.id = id; this.la = la; this.lo = lo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClusterUnitWrapped{" + "id=" + id + ", la=" + la + ", lo=" + lo + '}';
        }

    }

    public class ClusterUnitRequest {
        //...
        ClusterUnitWrapped u;

        //...
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClusterUnitRequest{" + "u=" + u + '}';
        }
    }

    private class ClusterUnitDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ClusterUnitWrapped> {
        public ClusterUnitWrapped deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> map : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
                String id = map.getKey().toString(); //Obviously is going to iterate only once.
                Double la = map.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("la").getAsDouble();
                Double lo = map.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("lo").getAsDouble();
                return new ClusterUnitWrapped(id, la, lo);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void run() {
        String json = "{\"u\":{\"53bde5b5e4fc4978c0000015\": { \"la\": 40.772673, \"lo\":9.6657388}}}";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(ClusterUnitWrapped.class, new ClusterUnitDeserializer())
                .create();
        ClusterUnitRequest u = gson.fromJson(json, ClusterUnitRequest.class);
        System.out.println(u.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: it's not the actual version of the code that I used, but it was really inspiring, thanks! :)